# How to get rendered JSX in React?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Imagine a `Container` component that renders a `div` with the specified `height`, e.g.:

```
<Container height="80">
  Hello World
</Container>
```

[image]

and `MyHeader` component that renders a `Container` with a certain `height`, e.g.:

```
function MyHeader() {
  return (
    <Container height="100">
      Header content goes here
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Now, I'd like to implement a `Fixed` component that looks like this:

```
<Fixed>
  <Fixed.Item>
    <MyHeader />
  </Fixed.Item>
  <Fixed.Content>
    Some content goes here
  </Fixed.Content>
</Fixed>
```

When rendering `Fixed.Content` I'd like to automatically set its offset to 100px (since `MyHeader` is 100px high).

Is there a way for the `Fixed` component to get `MyHeader`'s `height` so it could pass it to `Fixed.Content`?

Is there a better way to automate this?

**Note:** Using `useEffect` (or `componentDidMount`) is not an option because I'd like it to work in server rendered environments.

Comment: Can you just pass height as a prop to `MyHeader` in `Fixed`?

Comment: Not really. Only `MyHeader` knows what it actually renders and its `height`. What we can assume here though is that it always renders a `Container` with the `height` prop set.

Comment: Maybe try using `ref` with `MyHeader` then you can use `clientHeight` property from there to offset your `Fixed.Content`

Comment: Is there any reason the content needs to be placed below the header using an offset? Is simply stacking them in a block or flex display an option?

Comment: I want the header to be fixed/sticky.

Comment: Not possible to calculate a `DOM` element within an SSR environment (since the DOM doesn't exist). Instead, you'll want to lazy load it: https://gist.github.com/gaearon/e7d97cdf38a2907924ea12e4ebdf3c85. That said, I'm not 100% sure what you mean by `offset by 100px`. If both elements are placed within a css `fixed` element, then you won't need to offset it since they're both contained within the same parent. For example: https://codesandbox.io/s/hoist-ref-pnw4m

Comment: @MattCarlotta I know you can't measure an element without the DOM, but the height knowledge of `MyHeader` is in its rendering JSX, so I was hoping to extract the `100px` from there. In your CodeSandbox, the `Background` component has a calculated `marginTop` which I refer to as an "offset". In my example, it's equivalent to `Fixed.Content` having the `marginTop`. You probably assumed that my `Fixed` component has `position: fixed`, which is not the case. Sorry, naming is hard :)

Answer (score 1):

Generally you want data flowing down from parents to children. If that is not an option for you, you can use Contexts: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html. Especially check out https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#updating-context-from-a-nested-component. In your case, `MyHeader` could be a `Consumer` of your context and update it with its height, and `Fixed.Content` would also be a consumer that uses the value for its offset. But in general, I'd say what you're trying to do is a bit unnatural.

Comment: Using the context example won't work since I want it to work in server rendered environments where second render doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

You can use refs for that.

To solve your specific problem, first turn your `<Container>` component into a class component to be able to set a ref to it.

Then use `React.forwardRef` to forward the ref from the MyHeader component to the `<Container>` component:

```
const MyHeader = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <Container ref={ref} height={100}>
      Header content goes here
    </Container>
  );
});
```

Finally, create a ref hook in your component that renders the `<Fixed>` component and pass the ref to the `<MyHeader>` component. You can then also use the ref to set the height of the `<Fixed.Content>` component (or whatever you want to set), as follows:

```
function App () {
  const headerRef = React.useRef(null)
  return (
      <Fixed>
        <Fixed.Item>
          <MyHeader ref={headerRef} />
        </Fixed.Item>
        <Fixed.Content height={headerRef.current && headerRef.current.props.height}>
          Some content goes here
        </Fixed.Content>
      </Fixed>
  )
}
```

This seems to only render the `<App>` component once, so it should also work for server-side rendering. See the following code snippet as an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/get-height-from-header-gvvlo

Answer (score 1):

You can use [React Test Renderer](https://reactjs.org/docs/test-renderer.html) which renders React Node to an inspectable Object tree.

```
import TestRenderer from 'react-test-renderer';

const height = TestRenderer.create(<MyHeader />).toTree().rendered.props.height
```

This way, you can get its height without second render.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Container(props) {
  return (
    <div style={{height:props.height}}>
       your content
    </div>
  );
}
```

you need to pass height to `Container` as props which can varied dynamically.

```
function MyHeader() {
  return (
    <Container height="100px">
      Header content goes here
    </Container>
  );
}
```

for fixed also you need to pass it as props by having the height in a variable,e.g.:

```
function TopBar() {
  let height = '100px'
  return (
     <>
       <MyHeader height={height} />
       <FixedComponent height={height} />
     </> 
  );
}
```

Comment: The whole point of the question is to avoid doing what you are suggesting. I'd like to automate the `height` knowledge and have `Fixed.Content` to figure this out based on what's rendered in `Fixed.Item`.

Comment: In this case, you need to get the header height `ele.style.height` and you can use it in `Fixed.Content`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pass height prop from `MyHeader` to `Fixed`. And then `Fixed` to `Fixed.Content`. For example you can do similar to the following:

**MyHeader.jsx**

```
class MyHeader extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            height: 100
        }
        this.props.setHeaderOffset(this.state.height)
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Container height={this.state.height}>
            </Container>
        )
    }
}
```

**Fixed.jsx**

```
class Fixed extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            headerOffset: 0
        }
        this.setHeaderOffset = this.setHeaderOffset.bind(this)
    }
    setHeaderOffset(headerOffset) {
        this.setState({
            headerOffset
        })
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <Item>
                    <MyHeader setHeaderOffset={this.setHeaderOffset} />
                </Item>
                <Content headerOffset={this.state.headerOffset}>
                    Some content goes here
                </Content>
            </>
        )
    }
}
```